# ActiveRecordのメモリ使用量を確認する方法は？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

railsのActiveRecordですが、SQLのクエリー結果をキャッシュしていると思います。

ログに、

```
モデル名 Load (0.8ms)  SELECT 以下略
```

と Loadと出ればキャッシュに保存し、クエリーの実行時間も表示。

```
CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT 以下略
```

と出れば、キャッシュから取得したことを示し、キャッシュから取得するのにかかった時間も表示。

と認識しております。
さてでは、キャッシュしているメモリの量を表示することはできないのでしょうか？
ログに出す方法ではなく、都度調べる方法でも構いません。

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

こんな感じのミドルウェアを差し込むと取れると思います。

```
class QueryCacheProf
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    @app.call(env).tap do
      GC.start
      memsize_of_all_before_query_cache_cleared = ObjectSpace.memsize_of_all
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.clear_query_cache
      GC.start
      memsize_of_query_cache = memsize_of_all_before_query_cache_cleared - ObjectSpace.memsize_of_all
      Rails.logger.info "memsize of query cache: #{memsize_of_query_cache}"
    end
  end
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_after ActiveRecord::QueryCache, QueryCacheProf
```

### リクエスト中のクエリにキャッシュが効く仕組み

`bundle exec rake middleware`を実行すると`use ActiveRecord::QueryCache`の行が表示されるかと思います。

ActiveRecordが差し込むRackミドルウェアで、このミドルウェアがリクエスト中の同一クエリの結果をキャッシュしています。

具体的に差し込んでいる箇所は以下です。
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0c7916952e0f6110e10a2968cbdab5326f571924/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L19,L20

具体的にQueryCacheのミドルウェアの実装を読むと以下のように`connection. enable_query_cache!`を呼んだ後でリクエストを処理しており、
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0c7916952e0f6110e10a2968cbdab5326f571924/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb#L34

`enable_query_cache!`を呼んだあとでは`@query_cache_enabled`が設定され
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0c7916952e0f6110e10a2968cbdab5326f571924/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb#L39

`@query_cache_enabled`が設定されている場合、select文の結果が`cache_sql`でキャッシュされます。
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0c7916952e0f6110e10a2968cbdab5326f571924/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb#L65,L68

`cache_sql`を読むと`@query_cache`に実行結果がキャッシュされているのがわかると思います。
ここにキャッシュされているサイズを測れば、どの程度メモリを消費しているかわかると思います。

Comment: ここでは雑にキャッシュがある状態、キャッシュを消した状態の差を測ってみました。よりよい方法が知りたいです。

Answer (score 0):

"ruby memory profiler"というキーワードでググると、いろいろ情報が挙がってきます。

- [Ruby プロセスを追いかけるツール(プロファイラとか)10選 - sonots:blog](http://blog.livedoor.jp/sonots/archives/39380434.html)
- [Ruby でラインメモリプロファイラ - Qiita](http://qiita.com/sonots/items/c14b3e3ca8e6f7dfb651)
- [Rubyでのメモリ使用量調査 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/kinushu/items/a2ec4078410284b9856d)
- [SamSaffron/memory_profiler](https://github.com/SamSaffron/memory_profiler)
- [ruby-prof/ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof)

実際に使ったことはないので具体的な方法を示すことはできませんが、上記のような情報源を調べていくと質問の回答が得られるかもしれません。